# Troubles on iphone - how to fix the white space under images and the cart view?

Tags: css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I don't have physical IOS devices, on my pc I have windows, and android on my phone, and everywhere in all browsers that things look right.
In two safari emulators too.
But my client sees the website [like that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxVY6H-oTvdgj1m0Y_T6dCirVtLB8DIJ/view?usp=sharing)
The big white space under images, no footer, scrolling cart page instesd of how it looks on my android
[image]

[image]

[The catalog](https://proledsmarket.ru/product-category/svetodiodnyie-lampyi/tsokol-yo-40/)

[Single product page](https://proledsmarket.ru/product/svetodiodnaya-lampa-e40-2/)

If you have mac or another device with safari - please look to the code inspector, what css element makes that and how to make it look right? Cause I can't test it physically.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `height: 100%;` property of `.slick-slide` class. If you remove it or set it as `auto` you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote that - .slick-slide { height: auto;} - did it help? You see?

Comment: I use iphone SE and for me it looks fine. Here are some screeshots:
https://imgur.com/trtLs20
https://imgur.com/2ejXtX9
https://imgur.com/7by6hSB

Comment: Gods, he has iphone 7, I have no ideas, only to use IE 2013.....

Comment: I do not know but when I check it with my iphone, the result was fine. I also checked it on Safari Responsive Design mode with iphone SE, 8, 8 Plus, it looks fine too.